# Android внутреннее тестирование в РФ

Tags: android, google-play, тестирование, google-play-console

Запустил внутреннее тестирование своего приложения в googleplay. У меня с разных заведенных мной, а также добавленных в тестовый список аккаунтов все прекрасно скачивается и устанавливается (проводной интернет). Установка проходит гладко как по тестовой ссылке, отосланной непосредственно на мобильное устройство, так и при клике по ссылке на компьютере (перед этим выполняется вход в аккаунт Google).  Стоит мне переключить на смартфоне Интернет-соединение с Wi-FI на мобильное Интернет-соединение (4G) - все, не загружается страница с тестовой ссылкой ("не удалось открыть страницу соединение было сброшено (-101)").
Никому из 3 сторонних тестировщиков, которым я передал ссылку, установить приложение не удалось. Либо такая же ошибка, либо err_connection_reset, либо ERR_QUIC_Protocol_ERR.
Может быть кто то с таким сталкивался, в чем может проблема и как ее решать?

Comment: Проблема в блокировках на стороне провайдера. Проверяйте через VPN

Comment: Знать бы какие VPN безопасны, и непонятно при закрытом тестировании такие же проблемы у людей как и при внутреннем?

Comment: Без разницы какое тестирование, пользователь должен подтвердить что он хочет участвовать в тестировании, а это делается только по специальной ссылке. Не доверяете VPN? Сделайте свой!